# Where can I find release notes for 'dot' release of Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

For example, I can find the [release notes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2-9/) and the [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/) for Azure SDK 2.9 but I can't find notes for 2.9.5.

I looked at the [releases](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/releases) and the [tags](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tags) in the GitHub repo but I can't figure out which release/tag corresponds to a given 'dot' release.

Anybody can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Azure SDK for .NET 2.9.5 is released at August 30. From the official documentation for [Azure SDK for .NET Release Notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn627519.aspx), wo could find that the release note for 2.9.5 is not provided in the last several releases of the Azure SDK for .NET.

Comment: Do you know a way to correlate a GitHub release or tag to a specific SDK release? That would allow me to look at the commits for the release.